# CakePHP find group by isn't in the generated query

Tags: mysql, cakephp, group-by, find, cakephp-2.0

We have an rather comprehensive find, see code below, with a group by part. For some reason the group part isn't working, it isn't even in the generated query. Because of this, we get double results in our find (why we wanted to use the group by function in the first place).

```
$this->Product->Behaviors->load('Containable');
$this->paginate = array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Reduction' => array(
            'fields' => array(
                'Reduction.id', 'Reduction.startdate', 'Reduction.enddate', 'Reduction.price'
            ),
            'conditions' => array(
                'Reduction.startdate <' => date('Y-m-d H:00:00'),
                'Reduction.enddate >' => date('Y-m-d H:00:00'),
            ),
        ),
        'Mediafile',
        'Deliverytime' => array(
            'fields' => array(
                'Deliverytime.id', 'Deliverytime.name'
            )
        )
    ),
    'fields' => array(
        'Product.id', 'Product.name', 'Product.slug', 'Product.price', 'Product.content_short', 'Product.metadescription', 'Product.name_short',
        'Category.id', 'Category.name', 'Category.slug',
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Product.status' => 'active',
        'Product.visibility' => 1,
        'Product.hidden_on_site' => 0,
        'OR' => array(
            array(
                'AND' => array(
                    array('Product.use_stock_count' => 0)
                )
            ),
            array(
                'AND' => array(
                    array('Product.use_stock_count' => 1),
                    array('Product.stock_count >=' => 1)
                )
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'products_categories',
            'alias' => 'ProductsCategory',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'ProductsCategory.category_id' => $cat_ids,
                'ProductsCategory.product_id = Product.id',
            )
        ),
        array(
            'table' => 'categories',
            'alias' => 'Category',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Category.id = ProductsCategory.category_id',
            )
        ),
    ),
    'order' => 'Product.price ASC',
    'group' => 'Product.id',
    'limit' => $limit,
    'recursive' => -1,
    'page' => $page_number,
);
$products = $this->paginate('Product');
```

This is the generated query:

```
SELECT `Product`.`id`, `Product`.`name`, `Product`.`slug`, `Product`.`price`, `Product`.`content_short`, `Product`.`metadescription`, `Product`.`name_short`, `Category`.`id`, `Category`.`name`, `Category`.`slug`, `Deliverytime`.`id`, `Deliverytime`.`name`, `Product`.`id` 
FROM `products` AS `Product` 
LEFT JOIN `deliverytimes` AS `Deliverytime` ON (`Product`.`deliverytime_id` = `Deliverytime`.`id`) 
INNER JOIN `products_categories` AS `ProductsCategory` ON (`ProductsCategory`.`category_id` IN ('15', '306', '308', '309', '26', '167', '248', '185', '115', '116', '23', '258', '201', '22', '16', '17', '25', '19', '18', '114', '27', '127', '158', '136') AND `ProductsCategory`.`product_id` = `Product`.`id`) 
INNER JOIN `categories` AS `Category` ON (`Category`.`id` = `ProductsCategory`.`category_id`)  
WHERE `Product`.`status` = 'active' AND `Product`.`visibility` = '1' AND `Product`.`hidden_on_site` = '0' AND ((`Product`.`use_stock_count` = '0') OR (((`Product`.`use_stock_count` = '1') AND (`Product`.`stock_count` >= 1)))) 
ORDER BY `Product`.`price` ASC  
LIMIT 18
```

As you can see, there is no `GROUP BY`. We also tried using `DISTINCT` on `Product.id`, but that also doesn't work. If you run the query and at the `GROUP BY` part yourself, we get the results we want.We have also tried putting the `group` part inside an array like `'group' => array('Product.id')`, but no luck there.

So why is our find ignoring our `group` part? And how can we make it so, that it isn't ignored?

Comment: Looking at the code example for [the custom query](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#custom-query-pagination), the Group parameter is supplied as an array.

Comment: We have already tried putting it inside an array, but no luck there. I should have clarified that in my post, I will edit that in to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was our own fault. Someone in our team made a custom pagination function which didn't pass on the group variable. I wasn't aware of that at the time. I just had an "i get it now" moment while I was using his function in a different project.